# Send value of a variable from one view to another - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

What I am trying to do is use a navigation link to open another view and in the second view use a variable from the first view. No matter what I try I can't seem to make it work. I'm new to coding so my knowledge is limited and I can't find a solution.

I want to get the value of the take off mass in the table:

[image]

and, for now, change the "yet another attempt" to the same value:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You know what. By pure fluke I managed to find a solution. Not sure what I did differently from my other tries but it now works. Thanks for a response though!

Comment: Hi, I'd probably be easier to help if you could provide a bit of your code. For example where are the values coming from (CoreData, e.g.) or what exactly did you try?